# Postgres Generated Column not Updating

Tags: postgresql, tsvector, generated-columns

I've found a strange example where a generated column doesn't seem to update when I would expect it to.

```
create table example (
  "id" bigserial primary key,
  "value" text
);
insert into example ("value") values
  ('A'),
  ('B'),
  ('C');
alter table example add column "vector" tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('english', coalesce("value", ''))) stored;
insert into example ("value") values 
  ('some'),
  ('thing');
```

I would expect all the vector columns to be updated and contain a vector of the contents of the value column, but some are and some aren't.  Even running an update doesn't fill the column.  It basically looks like:

| id | value | vector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  |
| 2 | B | 'b':1 |
| 3 | C | 'c':1 |
| 4 | some |  |
| 5 | thing | 'thing':1 |

The strangest thing is I have tried dropping the column, then re-adding it and I get the exact same results.  I've also had times where updating the value column generates the vector, but when I set the value column back to the previous value the vector is blank again.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Are you talking about 'a' and 'some' being stop words?

Comment: Yeah, the vector column should have been updated with a tsvector containing the contents of the value column like rows 2,3, and 5.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  When using the 'english' config for to_tsvector it is excluding some words from the vector.  By changing the config to 'simple' my issue was fixed.